# How many clients can a regular WAP (wireless access point) connected on a PC running PFSENSE can handle?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, lan, wireless-access-point, pfsense

I am planning to connect 1000+ client on one wireless access point through a Desktop running pfsense, no one will connect to the internet it's just for local stuff only (media server).

1. Is it even possible for a normal WAP(wireless access point, a lot of people tend to answer for wireless routers) to handle that amount of users, considering all heavy duty will be done by pfsense desktop and since a lot of tweaking would be done? if not what's the best approach.
2. I don't understand what makes WAP powerful ? because i see some WAPs claiming to connect up to 200 client or even more while others don't.

   3.Does the PC (running pfsense) Network Interface Card have something to do with it? some explanation would be helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if you connect many devices (10000+) on wi-fi router/modem without using internet, if they can affect the speed and how?

All of those devices use the same frequency, so only one of them can "talk" at the same time. Though with MIMO, several of them can "talk" at the same time, but that "several" is only a handful, so it doesn't really help for thousands of decices.

The "speed" isn't affected, but since all devices must talk after each other, the total **bandwidth** is split up between all the devices that need to transfer data.

On top of that, many typical home routers won't be able to handle that many devices in the first place.

So what you do in professional settings (hotels etc.) is that you have many WLAN devices (access points, AP) that are connected by Ethernet (LAN), and together they can handle ten thousand devices.

And it doesn't matter if the whole network is connected to the internet or not.

> because i want to do a project only based on lan without internet

If you mean "LAN", then you are talking about wired ethernet, and with a sensible topology of routers, that can easily handle tens of thousand client WLAN devices.

And be prepared to learn a lot about networking basics for your project.